# Replace blank in the place of some phrases in a random string

Tags: java, android, string

I want to write fill in the blank app with java. I have a paragraph that's string and I want to put some blanks in the string in the place of some phrases. The string is dynamic string. How can I do it?

This is the method that I take string value from api. The string vale is dynamic.

```
public void getText(){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    //client.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&rvsection=0&titles=Article&rvprop=content&generator=random", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    client.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&prop=extracts&exchars=1000&format=json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {   
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Log.d("response", "response string" + response); 
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject queryObj= jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");
                JSONObject pagesObj= queryObj.getJSONObject("pages");
                Iterator<?> keys= pagesObj.keys();
                while( keys.hasNext() ){
                    String key = (String)keys.next();
                    JSONObject randomObj= pagesObj.getJSONObject(key);
                  //here getting dynamic random string
                    String strExtract=randomObj.getString("extract");
                    String noHTMLString = strExtract.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");

                    setBlankInString(noHTMLString);

                    Log.d("response", "strExtract"+ noHTMLString);

                   /* if(noHTMLString.length()<300)
                    {
                        String constantStr= setConstantString();
                        txt.setText(constantStr);
                    }
                    else 
                        txt.setText(noHTMLString);*/

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public void setBlankInString(String str)
        {
            String fullString= str;
            //fullString value is random value
        }
```

Comment: Post your code please. It helps us to answer your Q without having to guess what is intended or how it works.

Comment: I posted my codes. I want to do fill in the blank program. Inside setBlankInString(String str) method, I want to replace blanks in the string phrases. But that string value is not constant. So, I still have no idea. Please help me.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is. Identify what section you want to be replaced by blanks, create a new string with the content of your string before that section, add a blank, add the content after that section.

Comment: How did you want to put blanks in the string? Randomly? Be precise about input and desired output. Give an example(s) perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty basic solution that consists of creating an array of the words in the String, using a randomly generated int to start at a random index, and then replacing four adjacent indexes with `____`. You could definitely expound on this more and customize it to suit your fancy, but this should give you a good starting point.

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "This is a random sentence. In this example, we will be replacing some of the words with blank spaces.";
        String[] array = text.split(" ");
        int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * ((array.length - 1) + 1));
        int minBlankSize = 1;
        int maxBlankSize = 4;
        int blankSize = minBlankSize + (int)(Math.random() * ((maxBlankSize - minBlankSize) + 1));

        for(int i = 0; i <= blankSize && randomIndex + i != array.length; i++) {
            array[randomIndex + i] = "____";
        }

        for(String word : array) {
            System.out.print(" " + word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of assistance! You could upvote this to show some more love :D